# Radiation Within a Faraday Cage - Can It Escape?

Tags: electromagnetism, electronics

so we all know that the Faraday Cage prevents most EM radiation from entering the Faraday Cage. But what about, if we place radiation within the Faraday Cage - can it escape outside? I sort of recall working in class on a lab and finding that yes, it does escape - because the charges go to the outer surface - but I am having trouble finding a source to verify this, and I am using this concept for a project. Many thanks!

Comment: A microwave oven has exactly this arrangement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a case of cage being a closed shell made of perfect conductor, no radiation should be present outside, because charges on the inner surface will move in such a way that all radiation is reflected from the inner walls back to the insides. They work like a mirror for all frequencies.

This is why perfectly reflecting cavity is used in analyses of equilibrium radiation, or why microwave oven has to be made of metallic walls - both to prevent radiation inside to leak outside.

In practice, some radiation always gets out because there are no known materials that are perfect conductors for all frequencies.

Comment: Thanks very much! But if I recall correctly, whether or not the object is grounded plays some role. If the object is grounded, then radiation cannot escape, but if it is not grounded, then radiation can escape?

Comment: I thought this too before, but for ideal closed conductive shell without holes and autonomously powered radiator inside it makes no sense. In practice grounding may help or hurt noise coming in/out, as radiators are powered by cables coming in from outside, and chassis has holes for wires, cooling etc. Then grounding may help but it may also hurt, it depends on details such as what is connected to what, and where the power/noise is coming from.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is extremely helpful and I really appreciate your detailed response! When you’re talking about grounding, what would be a situation when it could hurt?

Comment: I think in audio equipment, there are cases where zealous grounding everything actually hurts the signal quality rather than helps, but I don't know much about that.

Comment: Oh wow - that’s super interesting, thanks so much!